# Looking for the last row and have it fill the other column

Tags: excel, vba

I am newbie in here in Stackoverflow and in the VBA Field. Actually I need some help with my code.

I have created a macro and it seems there is something missing in my code.

**Scenario**:

1. If A1 = 0.5 then in column B1 should answered FLAT
2. If A2 = 2 then in column B2 should answered as PER
3. If A3 = 5 then in column B3 should answered as PER
4. If A4 = 0.1 then in column B4 should answered FLAT
5. If A5 = 0.2 then in column B5 should answered FLAT

The code that I have only looking for one cell. What I want is in column B my code will apply until the last row of column "A" that has data

```
Sub exe()
    Dim number As Integer, result As String

    number = Range("a1").Value

    If number <= 1 Then
        result = "Flat"
    Else
        result = “Per”
    End If

    'enter code here
    Range("b1").Value = result
End Sub
```

Comment: if your number can be `0.5` do not try to hold that in an integer which will will remove the decimal `Dim Number as Double`

Comment: Yeah that is why I put in cells called as value

Comment: I put it as a range("C3").value Its just a scenario...to get easily understand

I also include the code above

Comment: You know you can do this with a formula?

Comment: Yes I can do that But what I want is I want to add this in my  excel automation where the system can identified for its perspective number and each string so if this is <= 1 then the answer is FLAT so if this is greater than 1 then the answer is PER

Comment: You can use worksheet_change event to check for the value entered at realtime in Col A to update values in Col B

Comment: Oh! actually I could not do that why? if the 1 worksheet will someone will touch or change something the formula all of that  will get destroy that is why I want to make it in macro

Comment: No it will not get destroyed. It will do exactly what your macro would do

Comment: but is it possible that my question will get work? refer to body msg of this question

Comment: I gave you all 3 solutions in my answer below. take your pick :)

Comment: Hi @SiddharthRout what does it mean by relevant Sheet i got an error on this ,,,

BTW Thank you for the codes. but I try the last one. but got an error

Comment: Same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60565181/fill-specific-text-for-a-specific-column/60566813?noredirect=1#comment107153169_60566813

Answer (score 1):

I would recommned using a formula

```
=IF(TRIM(A1)="","",IF(OR(A1=0.1,A1=0.2,A1=0.5),"FLAT",IF(OR(A1=2,A1=5),"PER","")))
```

But since you mentioned in comments

> so if this is <= 1 then the answer is FLAT so if this is greater than 1 then the answer is PER – Kate Sayson 16 mins ago

So the above will change to

```
=IF(TRIM(A1)="","",IF(A1<1,"FLAT",IF(A1>=1,"PER","")))
```

Other alternative is to use the worksheet change event. This will only act when a value in Column A changes and will only update Column B. So your rest of the worksheet is safe.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim aCell As Range

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
        For Each aCell In Target
            If IsNumeric(aCell.Value2) And _
               Len(Trim(aCell.Value2)) <> 0 And _
               aCell.Column = 1 Then
                Select Case aCell.Value2
                    Case Is < 1: Range("B" & aCell.Row).Value = "FLAT"
                    Case Else: Range("B" & aCell.Row).Value = "PER"
                End Select
            End If
        Next
    End If

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

If you still want a macro then try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1

    With ws
        '~~> Find last row in Col A
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Loop through relevant cells in Col A
        For i = 1 To lRow
            If IsNumeric(.Range("A" & i).Value2) And _
               Len(Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value2)) <> 0 Then
                Select Case .Range("A" & i).Value2
                    Case Is < 1: Range("B" & i).Value = "FLAT"
                    Case Else: Range("B" & i).Value = "PER"
                End Select
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the codes @siddharth but still i got an error.

Comment: What is the name of the sheet